# Why does PYTHONPATH with trailing colon add current directory to sys.path?

Tags: python, import, pythonpath, sys.path

Consider a Python project like this:

```
foo/
    __init__.py
scripts/
    run.py
demo.sh
```

Under normal circumstances, attempting to import from the `foo` package will
fail if you run the script from the root of the project, because default Python
behavior is to add the *directory of script invoking the Python interpreter*
(and not necessarily the current directory) to `sys.path`.
([docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.path)):

```
python scripts/run.py
```

However, I recently noticed that such imports were working on my box, and I
tracked it down to some surprising behavior related to PYTHONPATH. In my Bash
profile I had added a directory to PYTHONPATH:

```
export PYTHONPATH="/some/path:$PYTHONPATH"
```

If PYTHONPATH is initially empty, that (somewhat sloppy, but commonly seen)
form of the command will leave a trailing colon:

```
echo $PYTHONPATH
/some/path:
```

I had always assumed that this trailing punctuation had no impact, but it
appears that the trailing colon was the cause of the mysteriously successful
import. Leading or trailing colons (or even a defined but empty PYTHONPATH)
will result in `sys.path` containing an empty string **before** the `site`
module loads, which in turn leads to the current working directory being added
to `sys.path`.

Here are a Python script and a Bash script to demonstrate. I got the same
behavior using both Python 2.7 and Python 3.3.

Python script: `run.py`:

```
import sys, os

pp = os.environ.get('PYTHONPATH')

try:
    import foo
    print 'OK'
    assert os.getcwd() in sys.path
    assert pp == '' or pp.startswith(':') or pp.endswith(':')

except Exception:
    print 'FAIL'
    assert os.getcwd() not in sys.path
    assert pp is None
```

Bash script: `demo.sh`:

```
# Import fails.
unset PYTHONPATH;  python scripts/run.py

# Import succeeds -- to my surprise.
PYTHONPATH=''      python scripts/run.py
PYTHONPATH='/tmp:' python scripts/run.py
PYTHONPATH=':/tmp' python scripts/run.py
```

**My questions**:

- Am I understanding the situation correctly, or have I somehow gone astray?
- Is this documented anywhere? I did not find anything. At a minimum, I am
  posting this information here in case it will help others.
- Am I alone in finding this behavior unexpected?

Comment: Could not replicate on windows.

Comment: You are right about what is happening and I find the behavior unexpected and undesirable. It would be worth a bug report to python IMHO except that longstanding oddities like this can break things when fixed.

Comment: Or maybe I take that back. `export "PATH=$PATH:" lets` commands in the local path be executed on linux. Python is working the same way.

Comment: @tdelaney Thanks – that's a good test. I guess the Python behavior makes sense in light of the Unix behavior ... but they both seem counter-intuitive. Maybe there's a deep logic here.

Comment: yeah - just repeated your discovery and then google for "python path trailing colon" and stumbled upon your answer. Seems sub-optimal to say the least.

Answer (score 6):

When modifying colon-delimited environment variables such as PYTHONPATH, PATH, CPATH, MANPATH, LD_LIBRARY_PATH, PKG_CONFIG_PATH, etc...  Some of these variables place special meaning to trailing colons, while others do not.

For PYTHONPATH and PATH, I would recommend prepending (or appending) new directories in a manner that does not accidentally introduce trailing (or leading) colons if the variable was previously unset:

```
export PYTHONPATH="/some/path${PYTHONPATH+":"}${PYTHONPATH-}"
```

(In the case of MANPATH and INFOPATH, you *do* want to introduce a trailing colon so that `man` and `info` will include their default search directories.)

Explanation:

- `${PYTHONPATH+":"}` expands to a `:` if PYTHONPATH is set, regardless of if PYTHONPATH is empty.
- `${PYTHONPATH-}` will expand to the contents of PYTHONPATH if it is set, but if PYTHONPATH is unset, then `${PYTHONPATH-}` expands to nothing --- just like the usual `${PYTHONPATH}`.

  - `${PYTHONPATH-}` is the same as `${PYTHONPATH-""}` meaning to substitute "" (nothing) when PYTHONPATH is unset.
  - The reason I recommend `${PYTHONPATH-}` over `${PYTHONPATH}` here is that `${PYTHONPATH-}` will not create an error when PYTHONPATH is unset and your script has executed `set -u` to raise errors on unset variables.

For details on the `${parameter+[word]}` and `${parameter-[word]}` mechanisms, see "Parameter Expansion" at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02

For details on `set -u`, see the description of "set" at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#set

Comment: `/some/path${PYTHONPATH+:${PYTHONPATH}}` won't raise an error if `PYTHONPATH` is unbound because the `${PYTHONPATH}` on the right only gets evaluated if `PYTHONPATH` is bound.  Also, maybe `/some/path${PYTHONPATH:+:${PYTHONPATH}`  may be desirable if you don't want to end up with a trailing colon in the case where `PYTHONPATH` started out set but empty.